# Set all properties to None mock.patch

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

Is there any way to automatically set all properties to `None` instead of `MagicMock` instances using `mock.patch`?

For example

```
import mock

class SimpleClass:

    def __init__(self, a, b) -> None:
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self.a = value

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self.b = value


with mock.patch(f'{__name__}.SimpleClass', spec=SimpleClass) as simple:
    print(f'a: {simple.a}')
    print(f'b: {simple.b}')
```

Results in

```
a: <MagicMock name='SimpleClass.a' id='2087851942152'>
b: <MagicMock name='SimpleClass.b' id='2087905629512'>
```

But I'd like to have the following if possible

```
a: None
b: None
```

Comment: Have you tried setting them to `None`? Doesn't that work?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Yeah setting individual properties to `None` does work. I was just wondering if there's a way to automatically do it for all properties

Comment: No, not that I know of.